# Dns.GetHostEntry doesn't convert string which contains IP

Tags: c#, system.net, system.net.sockets

The function `Dns.GetHostEntry` doesn't handle `ipaddresses` as strings e.g. `127.0.0.1` but if I pass `google.de` as a parameter it works quite well.

Am I doing something wrong ?

```
public static Socket connSock(string Server, int Port)
{
        Socket s = null;            
        IPHostEntry ipHE = Dns.GetHostEntry(Server);
        //IPAddress[] ipA = null;
        IPEndPoint ipE = null;

        foreach (IPAddress address in ipHE.AddressList)
        {

            ipE = new IPEndPoint(address, Port);
            Socket tempSocket = new Socket(ipE.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            tempSocket.Connect(ipE);

            if (tempSocket.Connected)
            {
                s = tempSocket;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        return s;
    }
```

Comment: What is the behvaviour you are expecting and what is the exact error message? For me, `Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1")` returns a list of addresses (both ipv4 and ipv6), but `tempSocket.Connect(ipE)` throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could mean you're system is unable to get the host entry. This occurs (for instance) when there's no PTR record defined for the given IP.